# Microsoft Access - Multiple Items Form Image

Tags: image, ms-access

I have 2 tables: One of them is named 'ImageDrive', and the other is named 'Person'. In the Person table, there is a field called 'Primary Image Path' and it stores part of the path, i.e., "\DefaultPicture\default.jpg". The ImageDrive table has a field Drive which stores "C:\MyDocuments\Pictures".

I created a Person form, with a form type of "multiple items form". I then removed the textbox and replaced it with an image control for the Primary Image Path field.

Now the problem is, how do I go about extracting the information from the Drive field in ImageDrive and combining it with the Primary Image path? I need to combine them in order to set the Image control picture.

I have tried using Expression Builder and came up with the expression `[ImageDrive]![Drive]&[Primary Image Drive]` for the image control source. However, when I click on Form View, it shows nothing.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Based on XP vs Win7 the file path for a user can vary.  Are you only using one OS?  And are you the one assigning all these paths, or does the user assign their own path and then you concatenate it after?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you wanted to do this in VBA or not, but here is a small bit of code that may help for getting the path of that user.  You can combine that with a Recordset to reference your other table of pictures.  Or use two recordsets, one for each table.

```
Dim myR as Recordset
Dim myR2 as Recordset
Dim filePath as String

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ImageDrive", dbOpenDyanset)
Set myR2 = CurrentDB.OpenRecorset("Person", dbOpenDynaset)

'When you open these two Recordsets they will open on the first record of each FYI
'You can either use myR.FindFirst or a Select statment to sort through the records

filePath = myR![Field_name_of_path] & myR2![Field_name_from_other_table]

'Now filePath contains what you need.

'You can also use Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents" 
'to get something like C:\username\My Documents and set that as a string as well

Set myR = Nothing
Set myR2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi TKEyi60, thanks for your reply. i have tried that before and it doesnt work.. but anw i got it solved. will post up the answer, thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

After including the image control, go to the control source of the image control. and using the dlookup method to get the drive, as the form is created by using the fields the Person table. Below will be the line of code to be put at the control source.

"=DLookUp("[Drive]","ImageDrive","[Drive] IS NOT NULL") & [Primary Image Path]"